# Set metadata in user_data for cowboy_metrics_h

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I include cowboy_metrics_h into stream_handlers in my cowboy application.

How I can put data in user_data?
Where I should do it?

Answer (score 2):

In [documentation](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.8/manual/cowboy_metrics_h/) says:

> The set_options command can be used to add additional metadata in the user_data metric. This can be used for example to add the handler module which was selected by the router. The option to be set is metrics_user_data. It takes a map which will be merged in the existing user_data map.

[Example usage set_options](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/2e8fcb9a9ef9ef9beff25ed4d48cf0d90609a69b/test/handlers/set_options_h.erl):

```
set_options(<<"metrics_user_data">>, Req, State) ->
  cowboy_req:cast({set_options, #{metrics_user_data => #{handler => ?MODULE}}}, Req),
  {ok, cowboy_req:reply(200, #{}, <<"Hello world!">>, Req), State}.
```